# Removing isEditing Icon in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to remove the isEditing red icon totally from the table, i also want to reenable the swipe for row actions feature it seems to be overriding.

At the moment i can either have no isEditing command and use swipe to get to my row actions, but cant have my rearrange icons and feature. Or i have isEditing enabled and cant swipe to get to my actions i have to click the massive red button, but i can have my cell rearrange icons...

Is there a way I can have swipe for row actions AND be able to rearrange my cells? WITHOUT the red editing icon overriding everything!

Screenshots of issue: I have to have this red icon to have the rearrange icons, and it disables user swiping for the row actions in pic 2...

[image]

[image]

Some of the current related code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        let userExercise = self.fetchedResultsController.self.managedObjectContext
        print("EXERCISE TO BE DELETED IS \(userExercise)")

        userExercise.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        do {
            try userExercise.save()
            print("DELETE COMPLETED")
            self.workoutDesignerTable.reloadData()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        self.updateExercise = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueEditUserExerciseViewController, sender: cell)
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return [delete, edit]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let UserExercise = fetchedResultsController.self.managedObjectContext
        UserExercise.delete(fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        do {
            try UserExercise.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    var movableUserExercisesArray = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    let movedObject = movableUserExercisesArray?[sourceIndexPath.row]
    movableUserExercisesArray?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    movableUserExercisesArray?.insert(movedObject!, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    print("THIS WAS MOVED FROM \(sourceIndexPath.row) => TO DESINATION \(destinationIndexPath.row)")

    // attempting to set index paths - doesnt work as we fetched new?
    movedObject?.arrayPosition = Int64(destinationIndexPath.row)

    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have added

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

which now hides the red icon, however i still cant swipe to get to row actions, removing the red button removes any ability to access them when isEditing is on, can the swipe access be restored?

Comment: "Is there a way I can have swipe for row actions AND be able to rearrange my cells?" - No, you have to create red circle with "-" yourself.